# <command-line>:0:8: error: multiple types in one declaration

Tags: c++, centos7

when i tried to execute Grammar server code(contains c and c++ files) in CentOS 7.5 am stuck with the following errors

ERROR obtained :

```
[command-line]:0:8: error: multiple types in one declaration
[command-line]:0:8: error: declaration does not declare anything `enter code here`[-fpermissive]
[command-line]:0:7: error: multiple types in one declaration
[command-line]:0:7: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/include/_G_config.h:15:0,
                 from /usr/include/libio.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:74,
                 from jsapi.h:47,
                 from jsatom.h:47,
                 from jscntxt.h:59,
                 from jsanalyze.h:45,
                 from jsanalyze.cpp:40:
jsfun.h: In static member function ‘static uintN JSFunction::offsetOfNativeOrScript()’:
jsfun.h:230:37: warning: invalid access to non-static data member ‘JSFunction::u’  of NULL object [-Winvalid-offsetof]
         return offsetof(JSFunction, u.nativeOrScript);
                                     ^
jsfun.h:230:37: warning: (perhaps the ‘offsetof’ macro was used incorrectly) [-Winvalid-offsetof]
In file included from /usr/include/time.h:37:0,
                 from prmjtime.h:46,
                 from jscntxt.h:75,
                 from jsanalyze.h:45,
                 from jsanalyze.cpp:40:
jscntxt.h: In function ‘JSContext* js_ContextFromLinkField(JSCList*)’:
jscntxt.h:2963:64: warning: invalid access to non-static data member ‘JSContext::link’  of NULL object [-Winvalid-offsetof]
     return (JSContext *) ((uint8 *) link - offsetof(JSContext, link));
                                                                ^
jscntxt.h:2963:64: warning: (perhaps the ‘offsetof’ macro was used incorrectly) [-Winvalid-offsetof]
make[1]: *** [jsanalyze.o] Error 1
```

I am not able to figure out the problem. Can anyone help me regarding this ?
Thank You

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal complete verfiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? We cannot say anything without looking at the code

Comment: Multiple types in one declaration let think that you have used a reserved word as a variable name... Just a wild guess because you failed to show the source causing the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have like set of files, am not sure that due to which file the error is caused. Hence i failed to share the code.

Answer (score 0):

above error got solved once autoconf-2.13 is done by installing spiderMonkey.
for more info about installation please refer the below site:
https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_SpiderMonkey.

Comment: to install autoconf-2.13 you can use  yum install autoconf213